# Probability limits resource

Tags: probability, self-study, references

I am learning about econometrics and am struggling with the proofs and applications of probability limits and how they about central limit theorem (CLT) and the law of large numbers (LLN).

Does anyone know a good resource or recommended text to learn more about probability limits, CLT, and LLN?

Comment: The question is too vague to determine which of the hundreds of probability textbooks available suits your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the resources. I am at an introductory level. I have used the theorems in econometrics proofs but I am looking for a better grasp of the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a range of reference (text)books depending on your background:

[Ross, S. A first Course in Probability](https://amzn.to/3h1M9Gt)

[Feller, W. An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications](https://amzn.to/2J2nhSs)

[Casella, G. and Berger, R. Statistical Inference](https://amzn.to/2Kb3Yap)

[Billingsley, D. Probability and Measure](https://amzn.to/2WAC0ah)

[Durrett, R. Probability (Theory and Examples)](https://amzn.to/2WqTcz4)

[Lesigne, E. Heads or Tails: An Introduction to Limit Theorems in Probability](https://amzn.to/3mwCDfJ)

[Petrov V. Limit Theorems of Probability Theory: Sequences of Independent Random Variables](https://amzn.to/34n3HIb)